# Expo Splash Image Reduces Quality when Building

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I'm using a regular splash image, but its size is getting reduced, and it gets pixeled when running an expo build for Android. I've looked on how to keep the image quality, but did not find any documents explaining. Does anyone know how to do that?

```
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash2.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#FFF"
```